# Where the "tab" database is located on my hardrive(Oracle 10g)

Tags: oracle10g

I am new to Oracle10g and i installed it on Windows.

```
select * from tab;
```

I want to know where the "tab" database is located on my hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not "a database" it's a table - or actually to be precise: it's a view that returns data from a table.

The data for the underlying table is stored in a tablespace which in turn resides in one or more files that were created when tablespace was created.

For more information please read the concepts manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/toc.htm